Find a match of 2 or 3 names in one cell, enter those matches into corresponding cell on another sheet?
Here is my sheet.
Master sheet column Q contains comments with driver names, frequently more than one name will be included. Column S is where the driver names should go. My current formula finds only one name, even if more than one is present. I need it to find all names present and enter like this: Kent, Kyle, Pitts.
DriversBusesEmojis sheet column I has the list of coach driver last names.
I have no idea how to do this. Ultimately I want those coach driver names in the Working sheet column S. If I use the formula to get them directly in that sheet/column, I cannot assign other drivers manually or make changes to coach drivers. My thinking is if a formula used on a different sheet to get the data I need in the column I need, then when the data is imported (a script already does the importing) it will bring that name/names with it and still be editable on the Working sheet.
Would a script be a better option? Can the current import script be modified to include finding the name/names and entering them into the appropriate cell?
I also have very little know how regarding google app scripts. I have gotten a lot of help and figured a little out myself. So I will need detailed explanations how to do this. The import script is complicated to my beginners brain, so I haven't been able to figure out how to incorporate this functionality so far.
Note: Whenever possible, I have incorporated the formula into the header title. For example on the Master sheet column S, the header cell has a formula that displays the header text and the formula. This way I don't lose the formula if I change sorting/filtering etc.
I also know messing with the form response sheet is not a good idea, but I'm hoping this one thing won't cause a problem anywhere. If there is a better suggestion, please tell me!
I've tried various formula solutions. So far I can only get one name to be found.
The formula is:
=IFNA(BYROW(Master!$Q$2:$Q,LAMBDA(g,IF(g="",,INDEX(FILTER($I$2:$J,$I$2:$I<>"",REGEXMATCH(g,"(?i)"&$I$2:$I)),1,)))))
The result is pulled into the Master sheet column S with this formula:
={"Coach Driver";IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jO8auzYZ6drlGi3m7lon6gHTBVboDNgH5e0x4OwQoAA/edit?gid=818123556#gid=818123556", "DriversBusesEmojis!L2:L")}


enter like this: Kent, Kyle, Pitts. The name "Pitts" doesn't appear on "DriversBusesEmojis"

"Master" appears to be a sheet linked to a form. Is this correct? And "Itinerary" is the last response value? So, Column S (Coach Driver) is added after the response? is this correct?

Kyle and James and Williams each appear twice on "DriversBusesEmojis" - are these different drivers or a duplicate? What is the likelihood of two drivers with the same surname?

You need to trim the values of the Driver names. Several have a single following space which will affect any search/find.

May I suggest an alternative. Use an onFormSubmit script to analyse each submission as it is received. I have a solution if you are interested.

Yes, the Master sheet is linked to the Form that we use to request a school bus for a field trip. I wouldn't normally mess with it, but I am trying to figure out a way to get these coach names automatically added to the driver column and still allow me to manually add other drivers in the same column. I corrected my list and removed duplicate names and added Pitts. Also removed the following space after names. Sorry, I missed those issues.

Every morning I run the Import script to check for new requests. Any new requests are copied to the Working sheet. My thinking is that there must be a way to alter that script to also include looking for names in the Comment column and entering those names into the Driver column. But I can't figure it out. So I thought a formula might do the trick if it's happening before the data comes to the Working sheet. If I use a formula on the Working sheet, then I cannot manually add driver names (the regular non-coach drivers) without screwing up the formula.

AND yes the last column coming from the form is the Itinerary column. I added the Coach Driver column for use with this formula. I know messing with the form response sheet is not best practices. I'm hoping I can get away with this one thing without breaking stuff. If there is a scripted solution, I'm absolutely interested in that!

Every morning I run the Import script to check for new requests. But if you use the onFormSubmit trigger, then any new requests will be processed as they are received. I know messing with the form response sheet is not best practices. I think that is a fair statement; OTOH, you could also use the onFormSubmit script to copy each new submission to a "Working" sheet (whatever that is) - so that the Driver names are configured to appear on the "Working sheet" rather than the "Master" (or not as you prefer). I'll post the script later today.

You have a Google Form where users can request buses. The Form includes a "Comment" field where, among other things, the names of drivers can be recorded. The Form is linked to a spreadsheet.
On the same spreadsheet, there is a list of driver names.
For each request/submission, you want to use list of driver names to create a new column for each submission that contains a comma-separated list of the drivers whose names appear in the "Comments".
Consider this script which should be triggered by an installable onFormSubmit trigger.

    function getFormData(e) {
    
      // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG
      
      // get  Event Objects 
      var values = e.values
      var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
      
      // number of questions in the form
      var itemCount = values.length
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: number of questions in response = "+itemCount)
      
      // copy the response to "Working" sheet
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      var workingSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Working03")
      var targetRange = workingSheet.getRange(editedRow,1,1,itemCount)
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: the target range = "+targetRange.getA1Notation())
      targetRange.setValues([values])
    
      // get the Comments value as a String
      var driverComments = e.namedValues['Comments'].toString()
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: Driver comments = "+driverComments)
    
      // get the driver names from Column O = 15
      var driverSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DriversBusesEmojis")
      var driverCount = driverSheet.getRange("O2:O").getValues().filter(String).length
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: the number of drivers = "+driverCount)
      var driverList = driverSheet.getRange(2,15,driverCount,1).getValues().flat()
      // Logger.log(driverList) // DEBUG
    
      // create temp array to hold driver names from Comments
      var tempArray = new Array
    
      // loop through the driver list and test for inclusion in the comment
      for (var i=0;i<driverCount;i++){
        var result = driverComments.indexOf(driverList[i])
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", drivername = "+driverList[i]+", result = "+result)
        if (result >1){
          tempArray.push(driverList[i])
        }
      }
      // Logger.log(tempArray) // DEBUG
    
      // join array values as a string
      var drivers = tempArray.join()
      // Logger.log(drivers) // DEBUG
    
      // set the output range on "Working"
      var targetRange = workingSheet.getRange(editedRow,(+itemCount+1))
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: the target range = "+targetRange.getA1Notation())
    
      // update the Drivers column on "Working"
      targetRange.setValue(drivers)

}


Comments

Event Objects are used where possible.
Each submission is copied to a "Working" sheet so that the original form response is kept intact.
A loop is used to work through the Driver names and indexOf (the String version) is used to test for the driver name in the comment.
a temporary Array is used to accumulate any/all driver names found in the comment.
a join is used to convert the content of the temporary array into a comma separated string.


Driver Output


DriversBusesEmojis



Ok, I'm getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')
getFormData @ getFormData.gs:6      Should this be bound to the form? or to the sheet?

It is posting new submissions to the Working sheet on form submit. But nothing is happening as far as the coach driver name.

It does work. What trouble-shooting have you done? Have you uncommented all the Logger statements and looked for inconsistencies? For example, are you picking up the driver list from "Column O"? nothing is happening doesn't give one very much to go on.

How can I run the script without having to fill out the form and submitting it each time?

I just went in and made most questions not-required so I could skip them. Working on this but I've got to call it a night. Got it to recognize some names. Seems like they must be capitalized the same as in the list. Also, it doesn't recognize all names. For example: steve, Larry, mike, Williams, mckethan, Judd - doesn't find any of these names even though they are all in the list. BUT if I enter Coach Copeland, it finds Copeland. This entry, Mike, Steven, Jon Cofer, Jimmy eby - found Cofer and Steve, but Steven is not in the list only Steve.

A Lowercase:  1) change var driverComments = e.namedValues['Comments'].toString() to var driverComments = e.namedValues['Comments'].toString().toLowerCase() , 2)  after var driverList = driverSheet.getRange(2,15,driverCount,1).getValues().flat() insert var driverListLower = driverList.map(item => item.toLowerCase()), 3)  change var result = driverComments.indexOf(driverList[i]) to var result = driverComments.indexOf(driverListLower[i]) B Bugs: change if (result >1){ to if (result !=-1){

Mike, Steven, Jon Cofer, Jimmy eby It found "Mike", Cofer", "Eby" and "Steven". I agree that "Steven" is not on the list. The issue is that the comment is unstructured; sometimes it is comma-separated and sometimes it isn't. For example, we manage to extract and match "Olson" from Jodi Olson will be driving and we will stop to feed them on the way home. Perhaps as the specific limitation(s) of this method become clear, an option might be to post a new question asking how they might be resolved.

HOLD THE PRESSES!! I couldn't sleep and I had a brain storm! I edited the form to include a list of checkboxes, one for each coach. So new requests with checked coaches import in with the names comma separated into the correct column perfectly.
